# Its always true that $f|_{A}^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}(C)\cap A$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let be $f: X \to Y$ any function and $C \subseteq Y$ any set.
I was trying to prove the following stament
$$f|_{A}^{-1}(C)=f^{-1}(C)\cap A$$
The inclusion $\supseteq$ is not that hard. If $x \in f^{-1}(C)\cap A$ then $x \in A$ and $f(x)=f|_{A}(x) \in C$  hence $x \in f|_{A}^{-1}(C)$. But i have problem with the other inclusion. If $x\in f|_{A}^{-1}(C)$, its obvious that $x \in A$ however is true that $f|_{A}(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean $(f|_A)^{-1}$? What you wrote makes no sense.

Comment: I mean the preimage of f restricted to A or $\{x \in X \ | \ f|_{A}(x) \in C\}$. Thou i thought that it was the same

Comment: Since we know that $x\in A$ it has to be the case that $f|_A(x) = f(x)$. The only time $f_A(x)\neq f(x)$ is when $x\notin A$, which we know a priori not to be the case. So your conclusion may follow.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Every function sends each point $x$ of its domain to a unique value $f(x)$. If $x\in A$, that means $f|_A(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, that was the part i wass missing